# VSD in rms voltage

Tags: power-spectral-density

I am looking at a datasheet where they show a graph: $V_{RMS}/\sqrt{Hz}$ as a function of frequency = VSD (voltage spectral density). The question is: how can a spectral density be in RMS? The root mean square is averaged over time or frequencies (Parseval's theorem)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are thinking of Power Spectral Density specifically. This is a common detonation for the spectral density for voltage sources (low source impedance). The actual power across the load will depend on the load applied, which is $V_{rms}^2/R$, assuming the load is significantly larger than the source impedance.

Once the terms are squared, the units will Watts/Hz, as a power spectral density.

For practical use of this, I do come across this when working with op-amp circuits (for example), and in the course of the design will have interest in knowing the rms voltage (and rms current) noise in the circuit. The noise will depend on the bandwidth, and I would use such a graph as you describe to integrate over the lowest and highest frequency in the bandwidth that my circuit will provide to come up with a total rms voltage quantity that I would then expect to have.  The integration needs to be done over the square root of the frequency, as power is proportional to frequency directly, so voltage is proportional to the square root of frequency (Hence the per $\sqrt{Hz}$ in the variable).  For instance, if the noise was constant over a range of frequencies at 20 nV/$\sqrt{Hz}$ and I had a bandwidth from 100 Hz to 1KHz, the total rms voltage noise would then be (20 nV)$\sqrt{1000-100}$ = 600 nV rms.

Adding to the answer given the comments below I show this picture clarifying how each "point" on the frequency axis corresponds to an exponential, not sinusoid waveform in time.  This also helps explain clearly the meaning of "negative frequencies", in that they are the exponential terms that are rotating clockwise (negative phase change vs time).

[image]

Euler's Identity is a great example showing this in action:

[image]

Here we notice that the magnitude of each exponential is constant vs time: $$|e^{j\omega t}|=1$$

And therefore the rms of the exponential function is the same as its magnitude. And therefore the rms of an individual point in frequency is the same as its magnitude. However the total power of all the points in frequency will be the sum of the squares. If we want to determine the rms of a waveform with multiple freqeuncy points, this would be accomplished by summing the squares which is total power and then taking the square root which is the rms (Scaling in FFT's aside).

As a quick sanity check, we are familiar with the rms for a sinusoidal waveform with peak amplitude 1 is $\sqrt{2}/2$. For the two impulses shown in the frequency domain for the cosine each with magnitude 1/2 (also shown from Euler's identity), total power is confirmed to be the sum of the squares of the individual amplitudes: $(\frac{1}{2})^2+(\frac{1}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{2}$, and the square root of this, the rms quantity is confirmed to be $\sqrt{2}/2$. Note in this case if we are relating to voltage terms, the resistance is normalized to be 1.

Comment: Immagine I get my PSD by fft and my VSD by rootsquaring the PSD. The PSD output gives the power amplitude as a function of frequency (imagine you have a sinus only). I don't understand how you end up with rms. P(t) = V^2(t)\R -> P(f)

Comment: The FFT result is a scaled magnitude quantity, not a power quantity. You get the power spectral density of the fft by doing a complex conjugate multiplication with itself. (or in dB 20*log10(abs(fft))

Comment: I took care of the scaling factor and the complex conjugate (I just didn't mention it). The point was to say that you get an amplitude, not rms

Comment: The rms of any individual frequency point IS the amplitude, since each point is the transform of exp(jwt), which has a constant amplitude. Further from Parseval's theorem you can see that the power across the entire FT output is the sum squared of the individual frequency amplitudes. For example, if you had just two frequency points, f1 and f2, the rms would be sqrt((f1^2+f2^2)/2). Consider a cosine wave that tranforms to -f1, f1 (two points), each with magnitude 1/2.    (1/2)^2+(1/2)^2 = 1/2.  Sqrt of 1/2 = 0.707 which is the rms for a cosine wave.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is in viewing each frequency term as a sinusoid; this is not the case, each one is an exponential which has a constant amplitude, and changing phase at the rate of the frequency, and therefore the rms is the amplitude.

Comment: Aaah ok, so you mean that if I consider a single frequency f1 then: sqrt(V(f1)^2) = V(f1) (given V positive)? Ahah ok then I agree, but I don't see the point of adding "rms"... Thanks!

Comment: Still a bit confusing, exactly for the reason you mentioned. I see each component as a sine :/

Comment: I think I have an error in my comment with the divide by 2 for the example of converting the frequency terms back to rms.... the rms is the square root of the power and the power is the sum^2 of the frequency amplitudes. So for two arbitrary frequency points f1 and f2, the rms is sqrt(f1^2+f2^2) where f1^2 + f2^2 represents the total power in the waveform. Agree?

Comment: Yes I think I totally understand your confusion, many people view the discrete frequencies that way which is incorrect. Perhaps recalling Euler's identity would help: cos(theta) = 0.5 exp(j theta)+ 0.5 exp(-j theta), and realizing the K exp(j theta) is just another form of writing K with angle theta. Thus a single point on the frequency domain is a phasor with constant magnitude rotating at rate w (exp(jwt)).   Also this should clear up what "negative frequency" is: the phasor spins clockwise, while for postiive frequencies the phasor spins counter-clockwise!

Answer (score 0):

The power spectral density gives the time-averaged average power as a function of frequency, therefore the voltage spectral density $V(f)$ should give the RMS voltage  *of the harmonic component at frequency $f$*.

(RMS voltage is derived such that power computation formulae are the same as their DC equivalents, so it would make logical sense for the voltage spectral density to be RMS voltage.)

Comment: This is exactly the source of my confusion. Immagine I get my PSD by fft and my VSD by rootsquaring the PSD. But the output of the fft gives the amplitude as a function of frequency and not the rms...

Comment: That is a common confusion. There is some nuance that understanding might help you.

FFT and the power spectral density are different concepts.

As you correctly noted, the FFT gives the amplitude as a function of frequency. But the power spectral density is not defined by the FFT of the time-domain signal-- it is defined by the Wiener–Khinchin theorem (the PSD is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation), and the PSD does not give amplitude as a function of frequency, but it gives average statistical power as a function of frequency. RMS voltage is just the scaled square root

Comment: (RMS voltage is equivalent to the statistical standard deviation of the signal is ergodic, which is a commonly used assumption)

Comment: Ok I'll read about the theorem you just mentioned, but the FFT and PSD are in some sense correlated, aren't they? (Example: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/power-spectral-density-estimates-using-fft.html;jsessionid=9e29ed208fd99fc45612ab73c025)

Comment: You are correct that they are related indeed! The FFT can be used to approximate the PSD-- there are many different methods for doing this. Some common ones are the periodogram, Welch's method, and the Blackman-Tukey method, but at best they only approximate the "true" PSD.

Comment: One additional source of confusion is the fact that PSD can be defined in different contexts, depending on whether the signal is random or deterministic. If it is a random signal (like all "real life" signals), then the Wiener-Khinchin theorem is used to compute it from the statistical autocorrelation function (assuming the signal is wide-sense stationary). If it is deterministic and periodic, then it can be computed by Parseval's theorem from the Fourier coefficients (and the FFT can be used to compute this).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any reference you suggest? It would be great something not too far away from applications (to understand what everything represents in real life) but with still a good level of mathematical formalism.

Comment: This is kind of a cop out, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density actually gives a pretty decent derivation of where it comes from. 

(P.S. If you liked my answer, a checkmark would be appreciated :))